# Does UWP supports launch mode like Android?

Tags: c#, uwp

Android has launch mode like singleTask, singleTop, etc. Does UWP has this kind of launch mode? If not, how to achieve it in UWP? Or is there some 3rd tool to make it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP has no such launch mode like Android. UWP has only one launch mode and single entry point. And UWP [`ExecutionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) contains  **NotRunning**, **Suspended**, **Terminated** ,**ClosedByUser**,**Running** state. Each time the app starts, it needs to complete the life cycle process specified by UWP.

However, UWP support multi-instance and multi-View, you could open uwp app with multi-instance, For more detail please refer [Create a multi-instance Universal Windows App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/multi-instance-uwp) and [Show multiple views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views).